# How do I append camera with camera track animation

Tags: 3d-view, camera, tracking

I want to append the camera that had animation on it (because of a 3D camera track) to a fresh 3D scene. How do I do this? When I append the camera into the new scene, it has no animation.

Comment: Have you tried appending the actual camera object? *File > Append > Your Blend > Object > Your Camera*?

Comment: @brockmann Yes. And when I do that, it imports the camera in the axis of 0,0,0 and with the rotation of 0,0,0

Comment: The camera solver requires a movie clip, perhaps you forgot to import the clip? If you do not need the clip, you can bake your track down or export as alembic.